# Git submodule update gives "error: invalid key (newline)"

Tags: git, git-submodules

After a painful merge, when I run `git submodule update`, I get this:

```
>git submodule update

error: invalid key (newline): submodule.external/mono-reactive
external/mono-reactive.url
error: invalid key (newline): submodule.external/mono-reactive
external/mono-reactive.update
```

What's the matter?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out, I had a particular submodule defined **twice** in `.gitmodules`.
Once I removed the extra entry, the error would be gone!

Comment: what a quick find! I thought I would be looking online for hours